# Can't pass a services to a controller in Ionic/Cordova/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, controller, ionic-framework

i have a big problem with my app. I followed a tutorial to implement a pdf creator, and for do this i created a controller in this way:

```
angular.module('Ambra').controller('DocumentController', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', 'InvoiceService', '$cordovaFile', '$cordovaFileOpener2', DocumentController]);

function DocumentController($scope, $ionicModal, InvoiceService, $cordovaFile, $cordovaFileOpener2) {
    var vm = this;
```

in app.js i have this:

```
var Ambra = angular.module('Ambra', ['ionic', 'Ambra.controllers', 'Ambra.services', 'Ambra.controllersProdotti', 'ngCordova', 'pdf'])
```

and usually when i want create a controller i use this:

```
angular.module('Ambra.controllers', [])

    .controller('home', function(currentUser, $scope, $state, $ionicViewService, $http, $ionicPopup) {
```

And this is the service that i can try to pass to my first controller:

```
angular.module('Ambra.services', [])

    .factory('currentUser', function() {
```

In my HTML i call the first controller with ng-controller="DocumentController as vm".

I don't know how to pass this to my first controller. If i wanna pass it to all my controller simply i add currentUser in the parameters of my function. How can i do that?

Sorry for my english!

Comment: Are you saying you're not getting your 'currentUser' service in the 'home' controller?

Comment: no, on the home all work well. I can't get it in the first, the DocumentController. in the other all work well! I tried add it in the parameters of the function but nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your Ambra module in app.js you should be able to use `Ambra.controller('myController', [])` to create additional controllers and `Ambra.factory('myFactory', [])` to create additional factories within the same module.

You would then pass the factory to the controller like this;

```
Ambra.controller('myController', ['myFactory', 
    function(myFactory){
        //Do stuff
}]);
```

in the dependencies to any controller you want to use it in.

Comment: Yeah my error was the order of the parameters. They must do the same in both declarations!

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following I think you are *redefining* the "Ambra" module which is bad.

```
angular.module('Ambra').controller('DocumentController', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', 'InvoiceService', '$cordovaFile', '$cordovaFileOpener2', DocumentController]);

function DocumentController($scope, $ionicModal, InvoiceService, $cordovaFile, $cordovaFileOpener2) {
    var vm = this;
```

I also see you're not passing the service in the injector - I am guessing you left that out intentionally.

[Here's a fiddle that should guide you](https://jsfiddle.net/0yzw7uwc/2/).  *The order of the code is important* of course since your module happy.

I trimmed off the unimportant dependencies to focus on the problem.

```
angular.module('Ambra.controllers', []).controller('home', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

angular.module('Ambra.services', [])
  .factory('currentUser', function() {
    return { name: "RamblinRose"}
  });

var Ambra = angular.module('Ambra', ['Ambra.controllers','Ambra.services'])

// BTW be consistent, compare how you're creating controllers 
// for 'Ambra.controllers' and this controller.

Ambra.controller('DocumentController', ['$scope', 'currentUser', DocumentController]);

function DocumentController($scope, currentUser) {
  $scope.name = "DocumentController"
  $scope.currentUser = currentUser;
}
```